# Hibernate: Saving a complex data model in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My data model has a network of entities. A set of entities that reference each other with `@OneToOne` , `@ManyToOne`, etc. Some of these references are defined to be `@NotNull`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserDetails")
public class CustomUserDetails implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;
    //.....
}
```

`CustomUserDetailsService` handles saving and loading instances of `CustomUserDetails` class from the DB and `UserDetailsRepository` is an interface that extends `CrudRepisitory`.

When user makes a call to `/signup` we want to create and save an instance of `CustomUserDetails` to the db. But before server persists a new instance of `CustomUserDetails`, it has to create a new instance of type `User` and save it to the db (as it is defined as `@NotNull`).

Does it makes sense to do this in `CustomUserDetailsService`, in the Controller? or where else ?

I'm afraid that the design gets too complex and there would be lots of cross references between service classes of different entities when the data model gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same style, you should have a class called something like **"UserService"**, that handles CRUD operations for users.
Class **CustomUserDetailsService** should hold a member that is **UserService**, preferably using @Autowire annotation.

Before creating a new custom user details, call the **UserService** to create a new user (if needed).

In principle it could end here, **CustomUserDetailsService** is familiar with **UserService**, but vice versa.
You have defined **cascade=CascadeType.ALL**, so if you delete a user, the customer user details are also deleted.

Just make sure that other relations the **CustomUserDetails** have their cascade defined correctly.

Comment: Interestingly, I just instantiated user in the `CustomUserDetailsService` and didn't use the service layer to save it in the db, but I can see it is saved in the DB. Does Spring handle this automatically ?

Comment: Hibernate is doing it. Though it when you'll want to view all places where you create a new user, it'll be easy to miss this one.

Comment: Do you mean if I just set attribute of an entity (`B.a = A`) and save that object (`B`), the referenced entity would be saved automatically (`A`), too ? So, there's no need to save the referenced object (`A`) explicitly, right ?

Comment: Well, you should be getting an error - TransientPropertyValueException. Can you post the code that supposedly managed to do it?

Comment: If entity A has a reference to entity B, and we want to create and save a new instance of entity A to db, do we have to first save the referenced instance of B and then save A to the db ? doesn't hibernate handle this itself ? This would become very complicated if it's a large graph of entities.